# Problem with rails + json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my controller admin

```
  def index_all_for_question_id

      @answers      = Question.find(params[:id]).answers


    respond_to do |format|
      format.ext_json { render :json => @answers.to_ext_json(:class => Answer, :include => [:respondent]) }
    end
  end
```

my dataStore in extJS

```
 var answers_datastore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
       url: '/answers/index_all_for_question_id/<%= @questions.first.id %>?format=ext_json',
        method: 'GET'}),
        reader: answers_reader
        });
```

My question is: When i trying to enter 
`localhost:3000/answers/index_all_for_question_id/551?format=ext_json` for example,

I get :

`{"results":2,"answers":[{"answer":{"scale":1,"inquiry_id":277,"created_at":"2011-05-30T07:10:22Z","updated_at":"2011-05-30T07:10:22Z","text":"dfgfdghfdhfdh","id":275,"respondent":{"created_at":"2011-05-16T06:47:08Z","updated_at":"2011-05-16T06:47:08Z","id":109,"user_id":6,"email":"xxx@xxx"}}},{"answer":{"scale":1,"inquiry_id":278,"created_at":"2011-05-31T12:33:36Z","updated_at":"2011-05-31T12:33:36Z","text":"lolololol","id":290,"respondent":{"created_at":"2011-05-25T11:22:55Z","updated_at":"2011-05-25T11:22:55Z","id":110,"user_id":6,"email":"xxx@xxx"}}}]}`

SO i dont what it! Every user can enter this line i get answers (if he not an admin). How i can solve this problem? Only admins can see this, for others should be redirect on some page or appears text "Sorry!".

Thank you

Comment: -1 this is very unclear question. I can't see any problem with JSON here. I suppose you want to allow only admins to access this method, right? How are the admins authenticated at this moment? admin=0 in url is a VERY bad idea of authentication. In this case, I'd suggest using HTTP authentication (it's built-in as part of Rails): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Comment: thanks for helping me. yes exatcly, buuuuut i want: if user type url that i posted so he get redirected to another page. Admin can. I dont understand how to do it, i have read this stuff on url you showed me but still nothing

Comment: That is a bit tricky to implement for HTTP Authentication. See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that the simplest solution is to write custom `before_filter` where you can check if user has admin role and redirect to some page if no also you can use `CanCan` for authorization purposes

Comment: yeah, thanks bt if i have this in url: http://localhost:3000/respondents?format=ext_json&_dc=1306937167419&start=0&limit=50&fields=[%22respondent[email]%22%2C%22respondent[created_at]%22]&query= , how in RoR i can say if admin i can see this url if admin = 0, redirect,?? this is soptisticated query in url :(

Comment: prams string is really long :) But if I got you right user should not be able to see the page if particular parameters are present So the question is -- what parameters? What parameters(in url) should admin see an user should not?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [HTTP authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html). Redirect is a bit tricky to implement, here's an example (using sessions):

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  USER_NAME = "admin"
  PASSWORD = "xyz" # PS: you should use hashed passwords

  def admins_only
    render :text => "TOP SECRET STUFF!"
  end

  protected

  def authenticate
    if authenticate_with_http_basic { |u,p| u == USER_NAME && p == PASSWORD }    
      true
    else
      if session[:http_auth_requested]
        session[:http_auth_requested] = nil
        redirect_to '/sorry_page' and return false
      end

      session[:http_auth_requested] = 1
      request_http_basic_authentication
    end
  end
end
```